# My code isn't returning in IntelliJ python. why isn't it returning? I know there's a basic reason why

Tags: python

How can i get this code to run in Intellij my run code only displays:

/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/name/Downloads/untitled3/.idea/python.py

Process finished with exit code 0

using the print statement 
running the code

```
 board = ["-","_","-",
     "_","-","_",
     "-","_","_"] 

 def display_board():
   print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
   print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
   print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])

print(display_board)
```

I want to see my work in run mode of Intellij

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you maybe want to actually execute `display_board` with `display_board()` inside `print(display_board)`.

After that, i assume you dont actually need the print for the `display_board` call, so `display_board()` should be enough.